# Styling Windows Phone 8.1/WinRT AppBarButton

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm currently looking to implement a CommandBar for a WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 app. Overall it is very straightforward but I am unable to style the control.

I have themed my app so that the accent colour has been changed to green. This works well for pretty much everywhere in the app (buttons, textblocks etc.) but not for the AppBarButton.

The brushes I'm overriding are SystemColorControlAccentBrush and PhoneAccentBrush but changing these does not make any difference to the colour of the AppBarButton when pressed:
[image: AppBarButtonPressed]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong/can this colour be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the CommandBar's foreground and background colors.

The command bar on Windows Phone is system UI not app UI and does not allow customizing the colors of individual AppBarButtons. Their colors always come from the CommandBar's colors.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this worked. I don't have full control over the colour of the button when pressed but by settting the CommandBar's background and foreground the button now inverts with a white circle outline. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worth noting, it seems if you set the foreground colour to white then the phone accent colour becomes the background of the button.

Answer (score -1):

try changing app bar button color

```html
            <AppBarButton x:Uid="SendMessageButton" Icon="Send" Foreground="" Background=""  Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSendMessageButtonEnabled}"/>
```

or change in code behind

```html
  AppBarButton app = new AppBarButton();
            app.Foreground="";
            app.Background="";
```